# How to hide a row based on condition in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  filename     path         Status 
    -----------------------------
    1.txt      D:\JI\1.txt     E
    a.txt      D:\JI\a.txt     D
    b.txt      D:\JI\b.txt     E
```

This is my datatable values.I want to bind this value to a gridview.Before that I want to remove / hide the the rows which having the status as 'D'.I used onRowdatabound event ,but its not working .please help

```
  dtTemSec = (DataTable)ViewState["SecDetails"];
 GridImport.DataSource = dtTemSec;
                GridImport.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply filter out the row before binding your gridview like this:-

```
GridImport.DataSource = dtTemSec.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") != "D")
                                .CopyToDataTable();
GridImport.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks Alot.I have one more doubt .How to add multiple conditions ??

Comment: @jithesh - You're Welcome :) Since it is a `Where` clause you can simply add more boolean conditions like `x.Field<string>("Status") != "D" && x.Field<string>("filename") == "abc"`